# What is the meaning of, “The like say”?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The like say - the ultimate sanction in matters of large importance - has not been given to the Trustees alone.

From an essay “Twelve Concepts for World Service”, written in 1962 by Bill W., founder of Alcoholics Anonymous.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks very likely it is based upon a misremembering.

Comment: It might help for you to add a paragraph for context.

Comment: OED **Like** (adj.) **3. Chiefly attributive. Similar or identical to something of the same kind previously mentioned or implied.** ++ **say** (n.) **1.c. An opportunity to speak, esp. to express one's opinion or feelings on a matter; a person's turn to make a contribution to a discussion.** -- 1996   *‘Well folks,’ said Ms. Rickster, ‘we know where we stand, but now it's your say. You out there, what do you think?’* -- 2006   *The manager sat us down for a heart-to-heat, an open forum for the players to air their grievances and for him to have his say.*

Answer (score 4):

In this [transcript](https://aabookclub.org/aa_bookclub/12concepts.html) from Alcoholics Anonymous material, a search does not find "like say". However it does contain this paragraph which contains almost the exact sentence quoted (my bolding).

> Exactly as Dr. Bob and I earlier had found it necessary to delegate a large part of our
> active authority to the Trustees, so have the A.A. groups since found it necessary to del-
> egate these same powers to their General Service Conference. **The final say — the ultimate
> sanction in matters of large importance  —  has not been given to the Trustees alone.** By
> the Conference Charter, confirmed at St. Louis, this authority is now delegated to the A.A.
> groups and thence to their Conference, a body which is a representative cross section of
> our entire Fellowship.

So I suppose that you are asking about a typographical error you found, which should be "the **final** say".

Edit: In a deleted comment, it was suggested that "like say" means " *equal* say", but that doesn't seem to fit with the semantics of the paragraph.